# Python Function returning "function at" rather than numerical value

Tags: python-3.x, function

I want the below code to return a numerical value as opposed to `<function exp at 0x101c22e18>`:

```
def exp(x,y):
    x**y
    print(f"exp of {x} to the {y}")
    return exp

test1 = 2
test2 = 2

testing = exp(test1, test2)
print(testing)
```

Why isn't my `print` statement returning `4`?

Comment: in your `print(f"exp of {x} to the {y}")`, is `f` in quotation or not? Otherwise, see my answer

Comment: You didn't say to return the results of the exponentiation. You said `return exp`.

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to output the value of x^y. You need to write

```
return x**y
```

Not return the function handle `exp()`

Comment: You should clarify the intent of your answer, i.e. identify the problem as written in OP's code.

Answer (score 0):

As Argyll has pointed out, the problem is in the function definition. Instead of:

```
def exp(x,y):
    x**y
    print(f"exp of {x} to the {y}")
    return exp
```

you should write:

```
def exp(x,y):
    result = str(x**y)
    return print(f"{result} is the value of {str(x)} to the {str(y)}")
```

In your version, you just returned the function itself (and that's what you got: the function object ). In my version, you'd be returning the *result* of the function. You don't want the function back, you want what the function *does* back. And you want it back as a *string* which is why I've used the str() function: to convert integers and/or floats to their string equivalents.

Yes, you *can* return a function *from* a function--it's an "object" like any other--and there are many uses of this capability. In your case, though, you want the result of x**y back and not the function itself.

Note that the "f" formatting you used is only available in Python 3.6 or higher.